# standard picture of the index map

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

In the above proposition,there is a remark,which states that the right-hand side of (9.6) does not depend on the choice of $v$.

For diffenrent $v$s,there may exist different $p$-s and $q$-s,how to show that the index map $\delta_1$ is well defined?

Comment: The index map is defined elsewhere (see 9.1.3 again, the fact that $\delta_1$ is well-defined follows from the universal property of $K_1$). This proposition says that the index map agrees with the quantity defined here.

Comment: I don't understand why the RHS of 9.6 does not depend on the choice of $v$.If we have two partial isometries $v_1,v_2$ such that (9.5) holds,then we can get $p_1,q_1,p_2,q_2$,how to show that $[p_1]_0-[q_1]_0=[p_2]_0-[q_2]_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side does not depend on $v$ **because** $\delta_1$ is already a well-defined map (see the previous section). The proposition gives that, for any $v$ satisfying the hypothesis, with $p,q$ defined as in the statement of the proposition, $\delta_1([u]_1) = [p]_0 - [q]_0$. So if $v_1$ also satisfy the hypothesis, with $p_1,q_1$ being the corresponding projections, then
$$ [p_1]_0 - [q_1]_0 = \delta_1([u]_1) = [p]_0 - [q]_0. $$
Also, if you are concerned with different $p,q$'s for the same partial isometry $v$, remember that $\tilde{\phi}$ is injective (by 4.3.1).

Comment: May I ask you this question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494030/isomorphism-between-k-1a-and-k-0sa